# How to make eslint work with dojo modules?

Tags: dojo, eslint

Mostly, dojo modules are are separatly loaded javascript files that look like this:

```
define(["dojo/moduleToLoad1","dojo/moduleToLoad2",....],
function(moduleToLoad1,moduleToLoad2){

var module = {

// do something here 
}
return module

});
```

Eslint of course does mention that the intial define is undefined. How can I make an eslint understand that define, is not an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [enable the "amd" environment](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments) in the Eslint config file, which will make sure `define` and `require` are available globally.

Comment: Do you see any difference to simply adding define and require to globals such as  `"globals":
    {
      "define":true,
      "require":true
    },` ?

Comment: That's a good question. I don't think there's any difference in terms of outcome, but setting the environment to amd makes the intent more clear I would say